# How to grant permissions to VS Code to modify files in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I connected VS Code to WSL and when I try to save changes in my `index.php` file the following message shows up.

[image]

I tried to change the permissions on `var/www/html` using `chmod` but nothing changed.

*So how to make VS code modify the file?*

Comment: "I tried to change the permissions on var/www/html using chmod but nothing changed." That's an intention and an interpretation, but it lacks both what you did and what happened. Also, before changing permissions of anything, what are the actual permissions? Further, using what user and where (Linux/Windows) is VS Code running?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even I faced the same issue on my linux system, following command solved it:

- Go to that directory from terminal.
- Write `sudo chown -R <username>:<group> <directory_name>`. This command will change ownership (both user and group) of all files and directories inside of directory and directory itself.

To know the username write `whoami` in terminal.

To know the group write `groups` in terminal (The first name in the list is your group name) for me both username and groupname was same.

Comment: just to clarify, on VS Code, did you choose the wsl terminal when opening the terminal, and then ran those commands? That will output the data for the user that is setup when setting up the user for the Linux Windows subsystem. And I keep getting the same exact error after running the command you mentioned... If I try to use the windows user + group in the same way, I am getting the error chown: invalid user. Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score -3):

Open VS Code with Root User permission.

Comment: What does "root user" mean in the context of Windows?

Comment: Just randomly assinging superuser privileges to a whole process because it needs access to a single file is bad advise. Understand the problem first, then pick a reasonable solution. Permissions are meant to protect, not to annoy.